# Installing Mechanize using easy_install

Tags: python, mechanize, easy-install

I've installed mechanize using easy_install on Windows 7 Admin account. However, when I try to setup/run another program that needs mechanize on a different account, it doesn't find it.
Any solutions?

Comment: Well I don't think it's a machine-specific problem. It's just got something to do with where easy_install places the modules and where python goes looking for them. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your Python installation location?

How did you run easy_install?

easy_install probably uses the default user account permissions and you need to manually change file permissions / ownership so that non-admins can see the files.

Generally, easy_install is designed for single user installations (development use) only. including  other platforms (Linux, UNIX). If you wish to distribute application / package which works well on your operating system you need to repackage it in a format friendly for this operating system.

lxml etc. Python packages come with .EXE installer. Perhaps you could check how installer of these packages have been done and apply the same installer creation script for mechanize.